How can I fix "Invalid value at 'version.config.rewrites[0]" with Firebase hosting configuration?
Let me give you some context, I'm trying to change the redirection of a function that is in the US region to a European region in an Angular project. Previously, the configuration was like this in the firebase.json file:
"rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "rendertronProxy"
        }
      ]

I'm trying to deploy to Firebase with this configuration in the firebase.json file and I get the following error:

Error: HTTP Error: 400, Invalid value at 'version.config.rewrites[0]' (function), Starting an object on a scalar field*

The configuration I am using is this:
"rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": {
            "functionId": "rendertronProxy",
            "region": "europe-west1"
          }
        }
      ]

According to the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=en-US#rewrites) this works but I get an error, does anyone know why? Is there any documentation that tells me how to do this for Firebase CLI version 10.6.0? I'm looking for information and I can't find anything, except for the link that I assume is for the latest version of the CLI.
I hope to be able to make it so that when I deploy to firebase hosting, my angular project uses the function in the European region, not the US region version.
